# Sitecore Dependency Injection - Registering services with the lifetime of a web request

Tags: dependency-injection

How can I register a service with "PerWebRequest" lifetime using the native Sitecore DI?

I can imagine I need to play around the `Scoped` lifetime and set the default scope to Web Request somehow? Did anyone try to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The default scope

With Microsoft DI, the `Scoped` lifetime will default to a request scope in ASP.NET.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options

> #### Scoped
>
> Scoped lifetime services are created once per request.
>
> ...
>
> Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests

Sitecore reinforces this behavior in a custom HTTP module defined in the *Web.config*:

```
<add type="Sitecore.DependencyInjection.SitecorePerRequestScopeModule, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecorePerRequestScopeModule" />
```

So the biggest scope in Sitecore is a request scope. That is the scope used by `Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator` and by `Scoped` services injected into your controllers and processors.

### Custom scopes

If you wish, you can manually define smaller scopes:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;

// ...

IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory =
    ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

using (IServiceScope scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    // request and use services here using scope.ServiceProvider
    ISomeContract service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISomeContract>();
}
```

The `IDisposable.Dispose()` method ends the scope lifetime. Once `Dispose()` is called, any scoped services that have been resolved from `scope.ServiceProvider` will be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

the answer above is abount correct. I also figured out that Sitecore 8.2 adds default hanhdel for `request scope`.

`<add type="Sitecore.DependencyInjection.SitecorePerRequestScopeModule, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecorePerRequestScopeModule" />`

There is also the registration in the container for the scope:

`Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ISitecoreServiceLocatorScope, Sitecore.Kernel`

I believe replaing that registration we can set our custom scope.