# Sitecore dependency injection leak - IDisposable transient services

Tags: dependency-injection

I'm getting a `System.OutOfMemoryException: Array dimensions exceeded supported range. in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CaptureDisposable`

Which appears to be where the DI tracks the transient services for disposal.

I've recently used the standard DI pipeline to register services and I only have 2 services (controllers) that implement `IDisposable`

Any ideas?

#### Update from comments:

```
public class IoCServicesConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator 
{ 
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) 
    { 
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<SiteSearchController>(); 
    }
}
```

#### Question

Does the Sitecore ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(...)) reference a IServiceProvider as a per request item?

#### Sitecore

It looks like the ISitecoreServiceLocatorScope is resolved from the static serviceProvider, ISitecoreServiceLocatorScope  is disposable so these references will build over time.

As ServiceLocator.serviceProvider is a static field on a static class I believe the ISitecoreServiceLocatorScopes won't be disposed until the app pool is reset?

#### Findings

It appears the static application service provider is not releasing Sitecore.DependencyInjection.SitecorePerRequestScopeModule.SitecoreServiceLocatorScope, this is Sitecore version 8.2

Comment: Paste the code of your controllers

Comment: Have you looked at https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/sitecore-dependency-injection-registering-services-with-the-lifetime-of-a-web?rq=1 _

Comment: I'm just registering the controllers as Transient, in debug they appear to be being created and disposed correctly.  My assumption is in the CaptureDisposable where its tracking the disposables its exceeding the limit ~2,147,483,647. So the service provider be being reused across all requests

Comment: public class IoCServicesConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        { serviceCollection.AddTransient<SiteSearchController>(); }

Comment: @MatthewButler for future reference, please update your question with code etc... You can't read that in the comments. I have updated your question for you this time.

Comment: Still isnt enough info here, more code, more logs please, and sitecore version, and MSDI package version.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the ISitecoreServiceLocatorScope is registered as a transient on the global ServierProvider

serviceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof (ISitecoreServiceLocatorScope), new Func(SitecorePerRequestScopeModule.GetScope), ServiceLifetime.Transient));

This appears to have been fixed in Sitecore 9

```
serviceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof (ISitecoreServiceLocatorScope), typeof (SitecoreSingletonServiceScope), ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
```